# Adapt .htaccess file to reach route

Tags: php, laravel, apache, .htaccess

I am using `laravel 6` and run it on a `apache/ubuntu 20` server.

My apache host configuration looks like the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /home/admin/Desktop/Code

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined


</VirtualHost>
```

My `apache2.conf` looks like the following:

```
Mutex file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} default

PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}

Timeout 300

KeepAlive On

MaxKeepAliveRequests 100

KeepAliveTimeout 5

User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}

HostnameLookups Off

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

LogLevel debug

IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf

Include ports.conf

<Directory />
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
        Allow from All
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory />
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

AccessFileName .htaccess

<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>

LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent

IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf

IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf
```

As I am running laravel on a development machine I do not want to change my document root to point to the  project.

My routes in my laravel app look like the following:

`web.php`

```
Route::get('/', 'IndexController@index');
Route::get('company/{symbol}', 'CompanyController@index');
```

In my `.env` file the `APP_URL` looks like the following:

`APP_URL=http://localhost/laravel_app/public`

I can reach my base url `/` the following way:

`http://localhost/laravel_app/public/`

When I go from `/` to another detail url f.ex. `http://localhost/laravel_app/public/company/AAPL`, I get:

[image]

My `.htaccess` in my `laravel_app/public/` folder looks like the following:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

In my `laravel_app/`-folder my `.htaccess` looks like that:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

</IfModule>

php_flag display_startup_errors on
php_flag display_errors on
php_flag html_errors on
php_flag  log_errors on
```

I tried to setup a route like this `Route::get('company', 'CompanyController@index');` and open `http://localhost/laravel_app/public/company`, but I didn't even jump with my debugger into my `CompanyController`. I got the `404` error.

Therefore I was thinking that my `.htaccess` file might be wrong.

Any suggestions how to adapt my `.htaccess` file to correctly open an url like `/company/{symbol}`?

I appreciate your replies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DocumentRoot` is wrongful for a [`RewriteBase`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase) with a default value of `none`:

```
DocumentRoot /home/admin/Desktop/Code
```

This should rather be:

```
DocumentRoot /home/admin/Desktop/Code/laravel_app/public
```

Then the default `.htaccess` file inside directory `/home/admin/Desktop/Code/laravel_app/public` should handle the rewriting - without having to change the value of [`RewriteBase`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase), (which would be the other option: `RewriteBase "laravel_app/public"`). Adding `ServerName` / `ServerAlias` into `VirtualHost` and the host-name into `/etc/hosts` is usually  better than keeping the path in the URL. Otherwise the only virtual host is the default host, which should rather be the last one in row, in order to catch all unmatched host-names (they're loaded in the order of their filenames).

See [routing](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/routing); it's all done in PHP, at least while the Laravel application's main entry-point `index.php` is being reached ([`xdebug`](https://xdebug.org/docs/install) break-points can only pause the execution, while there is an execution).